# Zend Framework 2 Segment Route matching 'test' but not 'test/'

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2, zend-framework-routing

I have two modules Admin and Application. In the module application I have the following route in my module.config.php:

```
'admin' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
            'route' => '/admin[/:controller[/:action]]',
            'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            ),
            'defaults' => array (
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Admin\Controller',
                    'module' => 'Admin',
                    'controller' => 'Index',
                    'action' => 'index',
            ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
            'wildcard' => array(
                    'type' => 'Wildcard'
            )
    )
),
```

The problem is that it is matching

example.com/admin

and is not matching

example.com/admin/

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert `[/]` to fix it. try:

```
'route' => '/admin[/:controller[/:action]][/]',
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an optional child-route which matches only a /. That should also work for the same problem with a wildcard (sub)route.

```
'admin' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/admin[/:controller[/:action]]',
        'constraints' => array(
                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
        ),
        'defaults' => array (
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Admin\Controller',
            'module' => 'Admin',
            'controller' => 'Index',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'wildcard' => array(
            'type' => 'Wildcard'
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'ts' => array(
                    'type' => 'literal',
                    'options' => array('route' => '/' )
                ),
            )
        ),
        'ts' => array(
                'type' => 'literal',
                'options' => array('route' => '/')
        ),
    )
),
```